# Redshift load for snappy compressed file

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

How to load snappy compressed file from s3 location to redshift table? How to convert snappy compressed file or ORC format into tab delimited .csv file?

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Redshift cannot natively import a `snappy` or `ORC` file.

The Amazon Redshift documentation for the [COPY command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) lists the following supported file formats:

- CSV
- DELIMITER
- FIXEDWIDTH
- AVRO
- JSON
- BZIP2
- GZIP
- LZOP

You would need to convert the file format externally (eg using Amazon EMR) prior to importing it into Redshift.

Comment: Thanks John!! is there any generic solution to convert compressed file (snappy compressed or ORC) into Redshift loadable format.

Comment: ORC and Snappy are almost exclusively used in Hadoop environments. If you aren't currently using Hadoop, you could fire up an Amazon EMR environment and use Hive to convert formats. For example: [How to convert .txt / .csv file to ORC format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25117760/how-to-convert-txt-csv-file-to-orc-format). I looked at [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/formats) but it doesn't support Snappy nor ORC. If you are receiving Snappy/ORC files, they are probably being generated by Hadoop, so that source system could convert it for you.

Comment: Thanks John. I am using  command hadoop fs -text  <compressed file> to convert snappy compressed file. But this seems only worked for snappy and not ORC.